# Ayuda con los Mapas de Google en Ionic 3

Tags: google-maps, ionic3, ionic-framework, geolocalización, apigoogle

recientemente me encuentro trabajando en una aplicación con el framework de IONIC 3, estoy trabajando con mapas de google ya logré generar un mapa en mi aplicación con mi ubicación exacta, pero no se como hacer para que el usuario **elija una ubicación cualquiera que no sea la que me genera por defecto** llevo varios días y no encuentro información que me ayude.

Answer (score 0):

Si ya pudiste generar  el mapa me imagino que tienes todas las configuraciones adecuadas. Mira este ejemplo:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/adding-a-google-map?hl=es-419

Le puedes indicar al usuario por medio de algún input la longitud y la latitud y lo guardas en un objeto:

```
var uluru = {lat: this.inputLat, lng: this.inputLng};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: uluru
});
```